# ARtoolkit - rviz

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I use the ARtoolkit library with rviz?

(Ubuntu 10.04, ROS electric)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33902/artoolkit---rviz/) by [Janina](https://answers.ros.org/users/1871/janina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the package [ar_pose](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_pose). It runs the ARToolkit marker detection and publishes both detection messages and transforms that can easily be visualized in rviz. See the package wiki page for screenshots and a demo video.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3